# How to add custom UIbutton into UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a question about customize `UIAlertView`

I am customize a `UIAlertView` from even the background and button. I add the custom button into it, however I can't trigger the action of the button. The custom buttons are added into `UIAlertView` , but how can't I do add action to them? Please help me out. Is it because `UIAlertView` can't let us have custom buttons?

```
UIButton *firstButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 90, 30)];
UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 120, 90, 30)];

UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kButtonBlackImage];

[firstButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstButton setTitle:@"Don't Favorite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
firstButton.titleLabel.font = BOLDFONTSMALL;
[firstButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelFavorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[secondButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondButton setTitle:@"Save Favorite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
secondButton.titleLabel.font = BOLDFONTSMALL;
[secondButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(addFavorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

[alert addSubview:firstButton];
[alert addSubview:secondButton];
```

Comment: It should work. Can you add screenshot of your alertview here & how you allocated the alertview?

Comment: No need I guess, Thats just violating rules of Apple and your application will be likely to get rejected

Answer (score 0):

```
[firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelFavorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 Add that buttons properly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom view for `UIAlertView`. If there is a problem with your `secondButton` its a problem maybe because you set the target as `nil`, it should be `self`

```
 [secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addFavorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Just tried and got it working with :

```
UIAlertView*testAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 140)];
[testAlert show];
UIButton*testButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[testAlert addSubview:testButton];
```

I'm able to use my `someAction` method.